# Android: Reacting to Contact Merge

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working on developing an app for Android and need to store contact ID's in order to keep track of a subset of contacts for use in the app.  I'm currently storing the ID's in a table that's used locally, but this table becomes inconsistent if a contact is merged with other contacts (the ID used to represent the merged contact often changes).  What is the best way to maintain consistency?

My ideas:

- If there were some sort of intent or system event that is broadcasted then I could listen for that.
- If the mapping between old ID's and new ID's is kept somewhere (ContactsContract.RawContacts?) then I could refresh the field whenever I detect that an ID is no longer valid.
- Run a background process with a content observer and watch for changes.  I'd like to avoid this if possible.

This question seems to tackle a similar problem, but for adding instead of merging contacts: [Reacting to new contacts in Android Contacts application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011111/reacting-to-new-contacts-in-android-contacts-application).

Any and all ideas welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the contact lookup URI (as a string). This URI is created from the `_id` along with the contact `lookup_key`. These two can build a lookup URI by calling ContactsContract.getLookupUri(). You can lookup the contact by calling ContactsContract.lookupContact() and querying `CONTENT_URI` or by querying `CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI` with the lookup URI directly. The Android docs say this about the CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI:

> A content:// style URI for this table that should be used to create shortcuts or otherwise create **long-term** links to contacts. This URI should always be followed by a "/" and the contact's LOOKUP_KEY. It can optionally also have a "/" and last known contact ID appended after that. This "complete" format is an important optimization and is highly recommended.
>
> As long as the contact's row ID remains the same, this URI is equivalent to CONTENT_URI. **If the contact's row ID changes as a result of a sync or aggregation, this URI will look up the contact using indirect information (sync IDs or constituent raw contacts)**.
>
> Lookup key should be appended unencoded - it is stored in the encoded form, ready for use in a URI.